# GMock bus error in destructor

Tags: c++, virtual, destructor, googletest, googlemock

I have the following classes:

```
class D1;
class D2;
class Base
{
Public:
  Base();
  virtual ~Base() { if (instance) delete instance; }
  static Base* GetInstance();

  virtual int Get() = 0;
  virtual int Set(const int val) = 0;
private:
  static Base* instance;
};

Base *Base::instance = nullptr;

Base* Base::GetInstance()
{
  if (some_condition)
    return new D1;
  else
    return new D2;
}

class D1 : public Base
{
public:
...
  virtual int myD1Method()
  {
      ...
  }
  int Get()
  {
     ...
  }
  int Set(const int val)
  {
    ...
  }
private:
// members...
};

class D2 : public Base
{
public:
...
  int Get()
  {
     ...
  }
  int Set(const int val)
  {
    ...
  }
private:
// members...
};
```

To test my D1 class, I created a mock class using google mock framework like this:

```
class MockD1 : public D1
{
protected:
  using D1::MyD1Method;

  MockD1() : base(Base::GetInstance()) {}

  MOCK_METHOD0(MyD1Method, int())

private:
  Base *base;
};

TEST(MockTest, TestD1)
{
  MockD1 md1;

  EXPECT_CALL(md1, MyD1Method()).WillRepeatedly(Return(10));

  EXPECT_EQ(md1.Set(10), NO_ERROR);
  EXPECT_EQ(md1.Get(), 10);
}
```

The test seems to work fine. However, I am getting a bus error at the end of the test. When I step through in gdb, it looks as if its stuck in a loop in the base class destructor and it eventually leads to a bus error. Would appreciate any inputs on what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this destructor:

```
virtual ~Base() { if (instance) delete instance; }
```

And it has nothing to do with GMock.

`delete instance` is calling `Base::~Base()` - and `Base::~Base()` calls `delete instance`- this is the infinite loop you are observing.

The proper solution is not to use singletons. You can have some factory instead.

You can also try to nullify instance before you deleting it - that should work - but still - it is not good design that every instance of Base is owner of Base::instance (i.e. control its lifetime):

```
 virtual ~Base() 
 {
     Base* instanceToDelete = instance;
     instance = nullptr; 
     if (instanceToDelete) delete instanceToDelete; 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to use a factory.